# ASP.NET MVC Razor View selector and model mapping/binding

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I was trying to create a page where I was displaying few controls and 3 of them are Country, State and City. Since these are common on few other pages, I did research to find the best way to create them in Razor view and I finally ended up using $.getJSON and then filling the dropdown select with options in javascript, following is the code form JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Meta/GetCountries", null, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
                    $("#country").append("<option>" +optionData.Text+"</option>")
                });
            });
    });
```

And instead of DropDownListFor or EditFor I used normal HTML select for this purpose. But then I wasn't sure how MVC binds each control with the field in the model. Because the HTML is not aware of any model, I know we use something like `m => m.Country`, so I looked at the HTML code of Razor view and I didn't see any special things, so I felt that may be it is handled by Name/ID that we specify in the HTML tags so I tried to use the same and it worked. So my question is, is this the right approach? Using the field name value as Name in HTML tag works fine, but would there be any problems in future with this kind of approach?

Comment: Can you post the Razor code for the dropdownlists?

Comment: Its better to use `DropDownListFor()`, even if you initially generate an empty list and later populate it with javascript (i.e based on the selection from another dropdown) because the helpers will also generate other html that may be necessary for unobtrusive validation (i.e. `data-val-` attributes) if your properties include validation attributes (e.g. `[Required]`)